# How to retrieve a list of NFT items from a collection on Magic Eden with curl?

Tags: nfts, magiceden

I'd like to retrieve a list of NFT collection from Magic Eden using `curl`.

I've checked the docs at [`/collections/:symbol/listings`](https://api.magiceden.dev/#8e6d2f4f-6168-4dbd-a9ae-49e33fbf515e), and I've tried to use the following request:

```
$ curl --location -s 'api-devnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/solice_genesis_avatars/listings'
[]
```

but it doesn't return any items. I've also tried to use `api.magiceden.dev` or `api.magiceden.io` instead, but these also fails. And I don't see any endpoint available which I can use for the main website.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found it at https://api.magiceden.dev/

> Mainnet: `api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2`

The following curl command works:

```
% curl --location -s 'api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/solice_genesis_avatars/listings' | jq
```